# Starting uWSGI instance fails with code 203

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I want to deploy my Flask app on Ubunut 16.04 with nginx and uWSGI but whenever I do sudo systemctl start nebulon I don't get an error but the status says the following:

```
nebulon.service - uWSGI instance to serve nebulon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nebulon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-09-16 18:08:35 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 18718 ExecStart=/nebulonapp/nebulon.sock --ini /nebulonapp/nebulon.ini (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 18718 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

nebulon.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve nebulon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nebulonuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/nebulonapp
ExecStart=/nebulonapp/nebulon.sock --ini /nebulonapp/nebulon.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In `/nebulonapp` I have the nebulon.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/nebulonapp/
wsgi-file = wsgi.py
callable = app
plugin=python35

master = true
processes = 5

socket = nebulon.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

The `nebulon.sock` is in `/nebulonapp` but it is empty. The status of uWSGI is the following:

```
uwsgi.service - LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/uwsgi; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2017-09-16 18:22:53 UTC; 10s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18828 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/uwsgi stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18854 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/uwsgi start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 16 18:22:53 nebulon systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).
Sep 16 18:22:53 nebulon systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)...
Sep 16 18:22:53 nebulon uwsgi[18854]:  * Starting app server(s) uwsgi
Sep 16 18:22:53 nebulon uwsgi[18854]:    ...done.
Sep 16 18:22:53 nebulon systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).
```

Testing uWSGI with the following command works though.

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --plugin-python3 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you use `ExecStart=/nebulonapp/nebulon.sock --ini /nebulonapp/nebulon.ini` where did you get that from? You need a executable to be launch in a service and not a socket

Comment: Thank you. I got it from another question on Stackoverflow. The tutorial I was following says to do it like this ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini. However doing it like that gives me the same error.

Comment: So you want to run this `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --plugin-python3 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app` as a service if I understand right? If so please change your service with that as the ExecStart and then show the status of the service after starting. Also are you using virtualenv or not?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that hasn't worked either. However I switched to mod_wsgi and Apache and it works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with permissions. The guide you are following from digital ocean is missing a crucial step - nginx uses the www-data group to create the socket, and because of that you need to give ownership of your project folder to that group and make sure the user you are executing with is a part of that.

Simply, run these 2 commands

`chown -R sammy:www-data /home/sammy/<project>/*`

`usermod -aG www-data sammy`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the exact same error. Turns out that I've forgotten to install uwsgi in virtualenv...
simple `pip install uwsgi` solved the issue for me