# Flask setup on DigitalOcean

Tags: flask, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I am trying to setup a Flask App on DigitalOcean but I'm facing the same error each time I run the below commands, I tried everything mentioned online but it didn't work

```
$ sudo systemctl start testflask
$ sudo systemctl enable testflask
$ sudo systemctl status testflask
```

That's the error I'm getting when running the command

```
● testflask.service - uWSGI instance to serve testflask
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/testflask.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-11-09 14:47:04 UTC; 126ms ago
 Main PID: 30495 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Nov 09 14:47:04 aipi systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve testflask.
Nov 09 14:47:04 aipi systemd[1]: testflask.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 09 14:47:04 aipi systemd[1]: testflask.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 09 14:47:04 aipi systemd[1]: testflask.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

testflask.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve testflask
After=network.target

[Service]
User=alexy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/alexy/testflask
Environment="PATH=/home/alexy/testflask/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/alexy/testflask/venv/bin/uwsgi --log-level debug --ini uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

uwsgi.ini inside /home/alexy/testflask/

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :$(PORT)

socket = wsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
processes = 5

master = true
die-on-term = true
module = wsgi:app
memory-report = true
wsgi-disable-file-wrapper = true
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your question looks similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257171/starting-uwsgi-instance-fails-with-code-203

The answer there may be some help.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but still getting the same error

Comment: What do you get when you run `/home/alexy/testflask/venv/bin/uwsgi --log-level debug --ini uwsgi.ini` from the command line?

Comment: after running /home/testflask/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini I got:
-bash: /home/testflask/venv/bin/uwsgi: Permission denied

Comment: Try to change the ownership of the `.ini` file to `alexy`?! 
Most of time permission denied errors have to do with ownership.

Comment: I agree - there is an ownership/permission conflict between the user running wsgi (your user alexy, it looks like) and somewhere that process needs to read/write from. Check the permissions of the directories where the wsgi.sock file is written and where the log files are written.